# command to install PCRE 7.2

Tags: apache, pcre, yum

My software works on shared hosting, but problems with login on private virtual. Developer says its a PCRE issue. Host says I have to do it myself. Root makes me nervous.

I think I can install yum, after which, what command do I run?

ie. "yum install PKGNAME"

I found this references on http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/i386/CentOS/

pcre-6.6-3.el5 1.7.i386 but presumed that was incorrect.

Thank you.

Comment: Just perform `yum install pcre`, provided you have configured yum to use proper repository. This should be a serverfault question

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems the problem is unicode related. Updating to 7.2 would still be ideal, but "yum install pcre" or "yum update pcre" both said I already have yum installed.

I found an article for:

http://chrisjean.com/2009/01/31/unicode-support-on-centos-52-with-php-and-pcre/

I ran this:

```
 rpm -Uvh ~/src/rpm/RPMS/x86_64/pcre-6.6-2.7.x86_64.rpm
error: open of /root/src/rpm/RPMS/x86_64/pcre-6.6-2.7.x86_64.rpm failed: No such file or directory
```

I didnt upload the file anywhere. I'm not sure where to put it, or how to get it there.